# What is the mathematical way to determine an angle from two given true bearings?

Tags: math, geometry, bearing

Given that I have two true bearings as a start bearing 315 degrees and an end bearing 45 degrees, is there a better way to determine the angle between the two true bearings?  The complication comes in when the start bearing is greater than the end bearing.  I have the following that works but I figure there is a better/mathematical way.

```
double tStartBearing = 315;
double tEndBearing = 45;
double tAngle;

if (tStartBearing > tEndBearing) {
   tAngle = tStartBearing - tEndBearing - 180;
} else {
   tAngle = tEndBearing - tStartBearing;
}
```

Expect the resulting value of tAngle to be 90.  Consider a start bearing of 0 and an end bearing of 359.9, the resulting value of tAngle should be 359.9, not 0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (signed) angle is always `end - start`. Assuming the start and end angles are both in the same range `[n, n + 360)`, their difference will be between `(-360, 360)`.

To normalize the difference to a positive angle in the range `[0, 360)`, use:

```
tAngle = (tEndBearing - tStartBearing + 360) % 360;
```

To normalize the difference to a signed angle in the range `[-180, 180)`, instead, use:

```
tAngle = (tEndBearing - tStartBearing + 360 + 180) % 360 - 180;
```

The above work whether the start angle is smaller than the end one, or the other way around.

Comment: Thank you very much!